# How to access the Magento Core Api using Ruby

Tags: ruby, soap, magento

I am new to Magento. How do I access the magento core API using Ruby? Are there any tutorials or blogs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think making use of the Magento web services API would be the simplest way to bridge ruby and magento code.

You can find the core api documentation here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/magento_core_api

Magento uses REST and SOAP for API access, both of which you shouldn't have too much trouble accessing from ruby.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this example: http://www.polyvision.org/2011/10/02/using-magento-soap-api-with-ruby-and-savon/

Answer (score 0):

I created a gem called magento_api_wrapper that will allow you access Magento's SOAP API using ruby. https://github.com/harrisjb/magento_api_wrapper

To summarize, if you want to use one of the Magento SOAP API simple filters, you can pass a hash with a key and value:

```
api = MagentoApiWrapper::Sales.new(magento_url: "yourmagentostore.com/index.php", magento_username: "soap_api_username", magento_api_key: "userkey123")

api.order_list(simple_filters: [{key: "status", value: "processing"}, {key: created_at, value: "12/10/2013 12:00" }])
```

And to use a complex filter, pass a hash with key, operator, and value:

```
api.order_list(complex_filters: [{key: "status", operator: "eq", value: ["processing", "completed"]}, {key: created_at, operator: "from", value: "12/10/2013" }])
```

This returns an array of hashes with all your Magento orders. Good luck!